# passing parameter to model via controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have created a small project that display clothing items that coming from a database in CodeIgniter. The data is coming from the database and it's working and I have put a where condition to check the category and where condition doesn't work. Instead of displaying the specific results it displays all the database table results. I'm passing the category parameter through the url. I have autoloaded the database.

This is how i passed the parameter in home page when user click the Men's link

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Products/view/mens">Men's</a>
```

This is the controller

```
<?php
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Products extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('GetData');
}   


    public function view()
    {
        $category_name = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->GetData->get_data($category_name);
        $result = $this->GetData->get_data();
        $data['result'] = $result;
        $this->load->view('products',$data);
    }

}

/* End of file Products.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/Products.php */

?>
```

This is the model

```
<?php
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class GetData extends CI_Model {


    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function get_data($category_name=0){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('mens', array('category' => $category_name));
        return $query->result();
    } 


}

/* End of file GetData.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/GetData.php */
?>
```

Database table fields - id,category,category_name,img_path,item_name

I used where condition to check whether category is equal to mens and if it is display the results..And there is one row with category = women in the table. But instead of displaying the specific results it displays all the results.

Comment: Why are you passing $categoryname = 0 in your model? remove =0 and check.

Comment: @jyotimishra: this is not the issue, he is trying to get the data where $category_name = 0;

Comment: @jyotimishra I have tried that already and when i remove that i get these 2 errors..

Comment: i get these 2 errors **Missing argument 1 for GetData::get_data()** and   **Undefined variable: category_name** when i remove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model:

```
public function get_data($category_name){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('mens', array('category' => $category_name));
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public function view()
    {
        $category_name = $this->uri->segment(3);           
        $result = $this->GetData->get_data($category_name);
        $data['result'] = $result;
        $this->load->view('products',$data);
    }
```

Check this.

Please check first value of $category_name exist or not.

// Remove   `$this->GetData->get_data($category_name)`; from controller as you have already  defining this again. Not getting why you are calling same function twice in your controller.